# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Spread' of undefined with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spreadjs

I have an AngularJS project where I'm incorporating SpreadJS.  I dynamically loading teh js and css files through gulp and these are loading into my main index.html file good.  However when I try creating a new "spreadsheet" for the first time I get this error:

> angular.gc.spread.sheets.10.0.0.min.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'Spread' of undefined
>       at angular.gc.spread.sheets.10.0.0.min.js:41
>       at angular.gc.spread.sheets.10.0.0.min.js:1107

Right now I've removed the html and controller code for generating teh spreadsheet, but the error persists so it seems I didn't add the reference correctly.  In my app module I juts added '        'gcspreadsheets' as part of the modue definition:

```
   angular.module('sp', [

        'gcspreadsheets'
    ])
```

And again I have added these in the head of my index.html:

```
   <script src="/libs/spreadjs/angular.gc.spread.sheets.10.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/libs/spreadjs/gc.spread.sheets.all.10.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

Any thoughts of why this could be coming?  I'm using the trial version for now prior to buying.

Answer (score 0):

Please switch the order of the script references

Hope this helps

[GC SpreadJS](http://spread.grapecity.com)

Comment: Thanks, I did eventually figured it our.